# Как правильно писать с точки зрения русского языка

Tags: орфография

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как правильно писать:

1. Рисунок 1, 2
2. Рисунки 1, 2
3. Рисунок 1, Рисунок 2

Comment: Строчной Р на клавиатуре нет? Почему после запятой прописная?

Comment: Shampar. Опечатался но сути вопроса это не меняет

Comment: А в чём суть-то?

Comment: Вопрос в следующем. Фраза из текста: Встречаются эвгедральные кристаллы первой генерации, также встречаются ангедральные кристаллы, развитые вторично в виде цепочечных выделений (рисунок 2-5). Данная фраза относится к минералу пириту. Пирит представлен на рисунках 2-5. Вопрос в том как оформить фразу "рисунок 2-5". Я думаю так: рисунок 2, 3, 4, 5. Может быть есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Варианты есть: слово можно сократить (рис.; таб.; илл.), и всякий прочитает его так, как привык. В остальном всё должно быть оформлено, как перечисление — через *зпт* и *тире* (для интервалов): *рисунки 2*, *4*, *5*; *рис*. *2 и 4*; *рис. 2 — 5*; *рисунки 2 — 5*; *рисунки 1, 3 — 5*.